Select an unaffected row from table to use in trigger
What I have is a database table CODE that is used to store various types of codes in the application. Due to customer requirements, I must now write a trigger on that table that creates a row to another table, that references two rows in the code table: the inserted/updated row and a second row.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FOO
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON CODE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    -- ...
    m_CODE_STATUS_ID   CODE.CODE_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT X.CODE_ID INTO m_CODE_STATUS_ID
  FROM CODE X
  WHERE X.CODE_TYPE = 'MSTATUS' AND X.CODE_VALUE = '0';
  
  INSERT INTO OTHER_TABLE (ID,STATUS,CODE_ID)
  VALUES(SYS_GUID(),m_CODE_STATUS_ID,:NEW.CODE_ID)
END

Which currently gives the error ERROR:-4091  ORA-04091: table CODE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
If I were only referencing the changed row, I could use the answer under this question. However, I need to reference a "third" row.
How do I accomplish this?

This can be done with a compound trigger. In a compound trigger, you can combine different firing times into a single trigger that shares a scope.
In this case collect the ids into a nested table in AFTER EACH ROW section, then loop over that table in AFTER STATEMENT.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FOO
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON CODE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    -- ...
    TYPE ID_ARRAY_T IS TABLE OF CODE.ID%TYPE;
   m_CODES ID_ARRAY = ID_ARRAY();

-- after each row runs after a row has been inserted or updated.
AFTER EACH ROW IS  
BEGIN
 m_CODES.EXTEND();
 m_CODES(m_CODES.LAST) = :NEW.CODE_ID;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

-- after statement is executed after the table is done mutating
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
  SELECT X.CODE_ID INTO m_CODE_STATUS_ID
    FROM CODE X
    WHERE X.CODE_TYPE = 'MSTATUS' AND X.CODE_VALUE = '0';

  FOR i IN 1..m_CODES.COUNT
    INSERT INTO OTHER_TABLE (ID,STATUS,CODE_ID)
      VALUES(SYS_GUID(),m_CODE_STATUS_ID,m_CODES(i))
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END FOO;

